# For Loop in PL/SQL

Tags: dynamic, plsql

I am new to `PL/SQL`. I have a scenario where we have one staging table `STG_MAIN_CF_EVENT`. It has the information that needs to be loaded into two different tables: `CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK_STG` and `CF_EVENT_STG`.

For every record in STG_MAIN_CF_EVENT, I need to create a primary key in `CUSTOMER_FEEDBACK_STG` and insert into this.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this in For looping dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_stg_main_cf_event IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   stg_main_cf_event
  ;
BEGIN
  FOR r_row IN c_stg_main_cf_event
  LOOP
    -- Access the fields by using 'r_row.fieldname'
  END LOOP;
END;
```